# Manually triggering a redraw on AnyMap

Tags: anychart

on mobile devices the map renders sometimes a bit buggy.. markers are moved or too big.. can't really describe what happens there, it just looks really weird. However it does fade away when I move the map a bit, so I guess they are redrawn that moment. So to do that automatically I was listening to some events and then moved the map just for a pixel.. is there some better way to trigger a redraw? as everybody can see the map moving for a pixel.

AnyIdeas?

//edit: after testing a bit more I can say that moving the map using the move method doesn't trigger a redraw, it only works if I move the map myself, e.g. by touch gesture

//edit2: for now I am using anyMap.zoom(1) for triggering that redraw, it works but seems like a hacky solution

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in 7.13.0, AnyChart team will try to fix it in 7.13.1 which is scheduled do be released in a couple of weeks. There is no good workaround at the moment, unfortunately.

Comment: What is the progress on this bug? Also I saw one on animating a 3D pie chart. Is there any progress on that as well?